# How do I make a html element scroll over another?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have 2 elements - one which is the page title and has a height of 100%, the other also has a height of 100%. How can I make it so that when you scroll down, the second element moves on top of the first? I know I can use z-index to make one on top of another, but I cannot get the scrolling to work correctly.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: If you want to achieve a "parallax" effect, you can use "position: fixed" on the first element then offset the second element by the height of the first element and apply a "z-index" greater than the first element.